# Can't create a CSS file in Visual studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Guys I cannot create a CSS file in VS code. it shows this '#' icon instead of CSS one

[image]

I used to create this CSS file without any issue before

Comment: what is the languageID of the file, `#` is just an icon, depends on your chosen File Theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have successfully created the CSS file in the directory where your index.html is present. Just write the CSS in it and if the styles are not applied then check if you have linked the CSS file correctly to the html or not. With your current setup you can link it with this link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

Put this `link` tag within the `head` tags

Answer (score 0):

the "#" is the basic icon in VSCode to define a css file, did you link your css to your html?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`

Comment: Don’t post code as image. Post it as text instead.

Comment: we are now in the writing of HTML5 and there we **close** `link` and `meta` tags, HTML5 is an XML file

Comment: @rioV8 html5 is **not** xml. `link` and `meta` are [void elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element) and are **not** closed due to that.